# error while loading shared libraries: libgbm.so.1: cannot open shared object file: Puppeteer in Nodejs on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, puppeteer

I'm using a Puppeteer module to **scrape** some data using Node.js. It was working fine on my Macbook but when I deployed the build on an AWS EC2 instance and hit the route that was scraping data it started throwing an error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libgbm.so.1: cannot open shared
> object file

Answer (score 91):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y libgbm-dev
```

Above command fixed my problem. While doing some research on this issue I also found some other useful links which might help someone.

[Answer which helped me](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/732#issuecomment-614809415) 
[Official Puppeteer Github Guide for different Platforms](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/732#issuecomment-614809415) 
[Medium Tutorial](https://medium.com/@ssmak/how-to-fix-puppetteer-error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libx11-xcb-so-1-c1918b75acc3)

Comment: The "guide" link points to the same place as the "answer" link.

Comment: Though this is related to Amazon Linux, I don't know why this answer mentioned about apt-get which can be available in debian. CentOS base Amazon Linux won't be able to use apt-get to pull package...

Comment: You just need to install `libgbm1`, installing `libgbm-dev` is overkill.

Comment: The only thing that worked!