# Start a puppetter in gitpod

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

when i start my npm run start command, that happens

```
TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/workspace/zanoni-bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:286:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/workspace/zanoni-bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:280:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:485:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe ENOENT


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/workspace/zanoni-bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:286:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/workspace/zanoni-bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:280:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:485:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) 
Unhandled Rejection at Promise Promise {
  <rejected> Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe ENOENT
  
  
  TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
  
      at onClose (/workspace/zanoni-bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:286:20)
      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/workspace/zanoni-bot/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:280:24)
      at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
      at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:485:16)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21
}
```

remembering that I'm using 'gitpod", I've also tried using another platform called "replit"

but I still couldn't start my code within these platforms, my computer is pretty bad so I use these platforms.

Comment: Pupeteer requires access to your browser to run the tests. I'm not sure how gitpod works but I am almost certain it will be incompatible. You may be able to run it on your own pc though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize the workspace image as the documentation says https://www.gitpod.io/docs/configure/workspaces/workspace-image#use-a-custom-dockerfile

Here's the `.gitpod.Dockerfile` I use, it's a modified version of the one in the [Puppeteer repository](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile)

```
FROM gitpod/workspace-full:latest

USER root

RUN install-packages gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/googlechrome-linux-keyring.gpg \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/googlechrome-linux-keyring.gpg] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && install-packages google-chrome-stable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-khmeros fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1

USER gitpod
```

And inside the `.gitpod.yml` use it as:

```yaml
image:
  file: .gitpod.Dockerfile
```

Comment: The first time I inserted the file, VS Code showed a popup asking to "Validate" the Dockerfile (or something similar) and everything worked fine, but after using a couple of GitPod sessions, it won't work anymore: program crashes asking for missing packages dependencies. Regardless of the changes made to .gitpod.yml or .gitpod.Dockerfile, there's is no popup asking me to "Validate". Maybe it's not loading the Dockerfile? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Replying to myself, [this answer worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67407105/10161228). Basically just
`sudo apt-get update`
`sudo apt-get install -y libgbm-dev`